# Flexbox - align centrally if 1 item, top and bottom if 2 items

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a flexbox way for me to achieve the following goal?

If there is one item in the flexbox, I would like to center it vertically.

```
 -------------------
|                   |
|                   |
|one item only      |
|                   |
|                   |
 -------------------
```

If there are 2 items I would like them to align to the top and bottom.

```
 -------------------
|first item         |
|                   |
|                   |
|second item        |
 -------------------
```

### Bonus Goal

Ideally, and I realise this is pushing it, if there are 3 items I would like to align them to the top, except the last, which aligns to the bottom.

```
 -------------------
|first item         |
|second item        | 
|                   |
|                   | 
|third item         |
 -------------------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`margin-top: auto` is the right thing here:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  /* for demonstration purposes */
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex > div:not(:only-child):last-of-type {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>one</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's some css-fu right there: `div:not(:only-child):last-of-type`

Comment: @Adam gotta love flex :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center an item vertically, firstly set the codes below for main container..

```
.flex-container {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: -o-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -moz-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        -o-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        height: 400px;
    }
```

Here, flex-direction: row; is a default value. You don't need to add this with your main container. 
You can also do this by the following way ...

```
.flex-container {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -moz-flex;
     display: -ms-flex;
     display: -o-flex;
     display: flex;
     height: 400px;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

=======================================
If there are 2 items you would like them to align to the top and bottom. 
Write the following code for your main container.

```
 .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

N.B ---- Justify-content always works to main axis whereas align-items works to cross-axis.
Hope, this will help you to solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks! I was using space-between initially but I didn't have much joy.  But Vucko's answer got me sorted by using justify-content:center; and margin-top:auto.

Comment: margin-top: auto is not a perfect answer because when you use more than two items. Then what will you do? You can also do this by flex-direction: column; for container and align-self: flex-end for the child which you want put the last. I have tested the code which I have mentioned. That works..

Comment: But @Vucko's answer with margin-top:auto; does exactly what I wanted it to do. With any number of items.

Comment: You can drop all the prefixed `display: -webkit-flex;`, as they will be useless, unless you also add prefix to the other Flexbox properties, e.g. `-webkit-flex-direction: column;`